# Get number of followers of a twitter account within a specified period

Tags: python, twitter, dataset, tweepy

I have the user ids of various twitter accounts. Now I need to find number of followers those users has within a specified time period. How can i do that. I have been using tweepy. There is a method to find the total number of followers of a user. But there is no method to find the total number of  followers within a specified time interval.

i used the following code

`bearer_token= 'xxx'`

`client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)`

`res = client.get_users_followers(user_id)`

This program return the total number of followers a user has till this date. I need to retrieve total number of followers a user has within a time period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has the answer in itself.
"There is no method to find the total number of followers within a specified time interval". That is correct, as you can see by the API documentation as well.
Here's another [thread](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-get-follower-count-at-time-of-tweet/74484/2) that specifies that this isn't possible for your use case.